# Bring the length of an array to another array in SAS?

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a big SAS table, let's describe the columns as, A nd B columns in character format and all other columns are vairable in numerical format (every variable has a different name) with unknow amounth length N, like:

```
A     B   Name1    Name2    Name3 ....    NameN
-------------------------------------------------
Char Char Number1  Number2  Number3 ..... NumberN
.................................................
.................................................
```

The goal is that the numerical array Name1-NameN will sum up downward through the Class=B (By B),
So the final table will look like this:

```
 A     B   Name1 Name2 Name3 ....  NameN
----------------------------------------
Char Char  Sum1  Sum2  Sum3 .....  SumN
........................................
........................................
```

To do this sum-up, I described 2 arrays. The first one is:

```
array Varr {*} _numeric_; /* it reads only numerical columns */
```

Then I described another array with the same length (Summ1-SummN) to do the sum-up process.

The thing is that I can only describe the length of this new array manually. For example, if there are 80 numerical values, then I have to write manually like:

```
array summ {80} Summ1-Summ80;
```

The code works when I write it manually. But instead I want to write something like

```
array summ {&N} Summ1-Summ&N;  /* &N is the dimension of the array Varr */
```

I tried with do-loop and dim(Varr) under the array in many different ways like:

```
data want;
array Varr {*} _numeric_;
do i=1 to dim(Varr);
    N+1 ; 
end;
%put &N; 
array Summ {&N} Summ1-Summ&N;
retain Summ;

if first.B then do i=1 to dim(varr); summ(i)=varr(i) ;end;  
else do i =1 to dim(varr); summ(i) = summ(i) + varr(i) ; varr(i)=summ(i);  end; 

drop Summ1-Summ&N;
run;
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea about how to bring the length of the first array to the second array?

Comment: Hm,if i understand your problem correct,  N is a datastep variable, &N calls a macro variable, so you must use  call symput('N',N); after loop or better just: call symput('varrLen',dim(Varr)); and remove loop (not sure if n is reserved from a global macro variable)

Comment: Now I tried with both after the loop with call symput('N',N); and inside the loop with call symput('varrLen',dim(Varr));

Both gave the same error for the following code:
array Summ {*} Summ1-Summ&N;

The error is:
 "Missing numeric suffix on a numbered variable list (Summ1-SummN)."

Comment: i guess you must use summ"&N"   , but i am not sure if you can generate a variable name in this way. Better try Keiths solution first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate and store the number of numeric variables in a previous step.  The easiest way is to use the `dictionary.columns` metadata table, available in `proc sql`.  This contains all column details for a given dataset, including the type (num or char), you therefore just need to count the number of columns where the type is 'num'.

The code below does just that and stores the result in a macro variable, &N. using the `into :` functionality. I've also used the functions `left` and `put` to remove leading blanks from the macro variable, otherwise you'll encounter problems when putting `summ1-summ&N.`

I've also added a 2nd solution based on your answer, but will be more efficient as it doesn't read in any records, only the column details

```
proc sql noprint;
select left(put(count(*),best12.)) into :N
from dictionary.columns
where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS' and type='num';
quit;

%put Numeric variables = &N.;

/*****************************************/
/* alternative solution */

data _null_;
set sashelp.class (obs=0);
array temp{*} _numeric_;
call symputx('N',dim(temp));
run;

%put Numeric variables = &N.;
```

Comment: I used your `proc sql` code right after the main table, but it gives `N=3` instead of `N=87` (it should be 87).
I am considering if I wrote any parameter wrong. I checked the table properties: `type='Number'`, so I chenged it. 

I also wonder about `memname`, is it my table name? (in that case, it is a temp table saved in `work` library)

Comment: @user3714330 I used the dataset `sashelp.class` as an example.  You need to change the `libname` and `memname` to whatever library and dataset you're using

Answer (score 1):

Now I found another solution with a little modification of the solution from @kl78

Before when I tried with `call symput ('N',dim(varr));` I forgot to change the numeric format and to remove the uneccessary spaces. When I run it without format, the code tried to find `Summ_____87`, so it gave error.

Now I run it with format, `call symput ('N',put(dim(varr),2.));` the code can find `Summ87`, so it is totally sucessfull now.

Comment: `call symputx` will trim the spaces as well, without the need for the `put` statement (which in your case only works if the number of variables is between 10 and 99)

Comment: I've added a 2nd solution to my answer, along the lines of yours, but made more efficient by not reading in the dataset records